# Variable name depending on a value

Tags: rust

I would like to create as many vecs according to a variable in a for loop. Is there an easy way?

In the example below, I would like to get 2 different Vec, the first called vec_0 and the second vec_1. Any ideas on how to do it or how can I overcome this situation in another way?

```
 for i in 0..2 {
        let vec_i = Vec::<i32>::with_capacity(100);
    }
```

Comment: No dynamic variables at runtime (thank goodness), but you can have a vector of vectors.

Comment: I don't believe Rust supports this kind of introspection. What is the end goal of doing this? How is it advantageous over having a vector of vectors?

Comment: isn't it the same problem? How would I create a vector (capacity of 2) of 2 vectors (capacity of 100) in this case?

Comment: A pretty basic solution: `let a : Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![Vec::with_capacity(100), Vec::with_capacity(100)];`

Comment: I mean, depending on the 2 value. If I change it to 3, I would like a vector (cap of 3) of 3 vectors (cap of 100). It's based on a value of a variable, which is 2 in this case, but could be 3,4 or 10... Is it possible in Rust?

Comment: Why do you want an outer vector to be with _capacity_ 2 (or 3, or whatever), and not of _length_ 2 (or 3, or whatever)? I.e., why do you want to not create the inner vectors when you're creating the outer one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vec`s can contain `Vec`s too:

```rust
let mut vecs: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![];  // or Vec::with_capacity(2)

for _ in 0..2 {
    vecs.push(Vec::with_capacity(100));
}
```